# Converting the values of a SortedMap to arrayList

Tags: java, arrays

I have a `SortedMap` currently, and I want to take its `values()` and convert turn it into a array list.

```
Map<String, String> myMap = transformToMap(myObject);
Collection<String> values = myMap.values();
```

values looks like this : `[[1,2,3,4]]`

how do I turn values into `[1,2,3,4]` as simple as possible?

Comment: Use the ArrayList Constructor that takes a Collection as an argument: `ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)`

Comment: @gtgaxiola Please write that as an answer so that I can upvote it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the ArrayList Constructor that takes a Collection as an argument:

[`ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(java.util.Collection))

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   Map<String, String> myMap = new TreeMap<>();
   myMap.put("a","1");
   myMap.put("b","2");
   myMap.put("c","3");
   Collection<String> values = myMap.values();
   List<String> val = new ArrayList(values);
   System.out.println(val);  
}
```

Which outputs:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: so I used that, my arrayList<String> convertedList came back as [[1,2,3,4]] still. @gtgaxiola

Comment: @JennyC Check how is your `SortedMap` implementing values().. As a test create a simple `TreeMap` (which already implements `SortedMap`) and you will see you don't get double brackets when printing `myMap.values()` method

Comment: Right, that's what I did, I created a new TreeMap passed in the SortedMap, then used arrayList passing in a collection, but still not working.. very weird. My original map is just a SortedMap

Comment: As a Test try the `main` method I added to my answer. If that output is correct, then that means the way your map is being populated has a behavior you are not expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Try using addAll method.
arraylist.addAll(myMap.values);